# Using wildcards in stream terminal operations

Tags: java, java-stream

Hi2all.

I'am reading a Java book and got to the chapter about StreamAPI classes.
So, my questions is: why in terminal operation methods using lower bounded wildcards, like:

```
void forEach(Consumer<? super T> consumer)
boolean anyMatch(Predicate <? super T> pred)
Optional<T> min(<? super T> comparator)
```

Indeed, in fact, you can use unbounded wildcards like this:

```
void forEach(Consumer<?> consumer)
boolean anyMatch(Predicate <?> pred)
Optional<T> min(<?> comparator)
```

Is there any reason to use exactly lower- bounded wildcards?

Comment: I think you left out the `Comparator` for the `min` examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use unbounded wildcards for these methods.

Suppose you are implementing your own `forEach` method. If it accepts a `Consumer<? super T>`, you can pass a `T` to it, because you know that `T` is a subtype of whatever the `Consumer`'s parameter's type is and can therefore safely make the consumer accept an element of type `T`.

However, if it accepts a `Consumer<?>`, you can't directly pass a `T` to it without casting. There is no guarantee that the consumer accepts `T`s and not some other type? Furthermore, as Louis Wasserman pointed out in his answer, you would be able to pass a `Consumer<Long>` to the `forEach` method of a `Stream<String>`.

Lower-bounded wildcards are as loose as you can get while also being typesafe. With just plain `Consumer<T>` and `Supplier<T>` parameters, you wouldn't be able to directly pass a `Consumer<Object>` to a `Stream<String>`'s `forEach` method without casting. With unbounded wildcards, you would be able to pass basically anything, which defeats the whole point of using generics.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong in saying that you can use "unbounded wildcards."  You can't, and the terminal operations you describe have the most permissive types possible.

```java
Consumer<Long> longConsumer = (l) -> System.out.println(l * 2);
Stream<String> stringStream = Stream.of("a", "b");

stringStream.forEach(longConsumer); 
// should not work, but would work if forEach accepted Consumer<?>
```